# Can't find DatePicker in XML layouts

Tags: android, xml-layout

In previous Android studio version I used DatePicker but now in 3.1 version doesn't exist anything as the same.
Is it any replacement for that?

Answer (score 2):

In version `3.1.2`, the Date Picker widget is present in the XML file.

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</DatePicker>
```

In an earlier version, the date picker used to be present in the Palette but from `v3.1.2` onwards it has been removed from Palette, so we need to write it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

The `DatePicker` widget in XML is not removed or anything, if that is what you are asking. 
Below is a proof of DatePicker widget on Android Studio 3.1.2
[image: DatePicker in Android Studio 3.1.2]

Try clean project, Build Project and restart IDE to see if the DatePicker in XML reappears.